# How can i make a list in a string to a true list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

### e.g.:

from :
`"[1,2,3]"`to `[1,2,3]`

as the function `int()` makes a `"5"` a `5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `json` and `ast` packages can help with parsing like this. In this case try:

```
import json
foo = json.loads("[1,2,3]")
```

or

```
import ast
foo = ast.literal_eval("[1,2,3]")
```

@Sid asks an important question in the comments:

*Why not use `eval()` as it is baked in and would not require the import?*

While it is technically true that:

```
foo = eval("[1,2,3]")
```

also produces the desired result in this case, @AndyLester importantly reminds us that *`eval()` can be dangerous*. Specifically `eval()` allows for execution of code not just parsing of literals. If we imagine that the following could be any arbitrary block of python and someone could pollute our input with it:

```
"print('Here be Dragons')"
```

Then the first two methods will throw exceptions:

```
foo = json.loads("print('Here be Dragons')")
>>>json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

and

```
foo = ast.literal_eval("print('Here be Dragons')")
>>>ValueError: malformed node or string:
```

While the third does

```
foo = eval("print('Here be Dragons')")
>>>Here be Dragons
```

our input was executed (dangerous) rather than simply parsed and worse, `foo` also is still `None` as `print()` has no return value.

Comment: Would not simply `eval` be sufficient?

Comment: `eval` would certainly be more dangerous.

Comment: @AndyLester how?

Comment: @Sid Unless you are absolutely certain that your inputs are safe, `eval()` would allow execution not just parsing. Try `eval("print('Here be Dragons')")`.

Comment: @Sid This is always my go to example of how `eval` can be dangerous. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081082/12479639

Answer (score 1):

This will correctly parse your list

```
k = '[1,2,3]'
list(map(lambda x: int(x), k[1:-1].split(',')))
```

Yields:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Great answer for "strings"! I *think* the request was for an array of int though. Easy enough to fix with a comprehension :-)

Comment: The question was how to make a string which contains a list into a list array.  This solution does exactly that.

Comment: The question specifies `"[1,2,3]"` to `[1,2,3]`. This answer does not do that. This slight modification would allow the expected result `[int(i) for i in k[1:-1].split(',')]`